# I need to add a second email address to this function from Google sheets

Tags: javascript, email, pdf, google-sheets

I have this script that sends an email to the email address entered into cell 'E6' of a Google spreadsheet. I also need to send a copy to another email address at the same time. Could you help me figure out how to modify this code to do that? Thanks so much for your help.

```
function sendSheetToPdfwithA1MailAdress(){ // this is the function to call
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheets()[0]; // it will send sheet 0 which is the first sheet in the spreadsheet.
  // if you change the number, change it also in the parameters below
  var shName = sh.getName()
  sendSpreadsheetToPdf(0, shName, sh.getRange('E6').getValue(),"Balance Over Burnout", "The attached PDF contains a copy of your personalized Wellness Wheel, and the answers to your questionnaire.");
 
}
function sendSpreadsheetToPdf(sheetNumber, pdfName, email,subject, htmlbody) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var spreadsheetId = spreadsheet.getId()  
  var sheetId = sheetNumber ? spreadsheet.getSheets()[sheetNumber].getSheetId() : null;  
  var url_base = spreadsheet.getUrl().replace(/edit$/,'');

  var url_ext = 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'   //export as pdf

      + (sheetId ? ('&gid=' + sheetId) : ('&id=' + spreadsheetId)) 
      // following parameters are optional...
      + '&size=A4'      // paper size
      + '&portrait=true'    // orientation, false for landscape
      + '&fitw=true'        // fit to width, false for actual size
      + '&sheetnames=true&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=true'  //hide optional headers and footers
      + '&gridlines=false'  // hide gridlines
      + '&fzr=false';       // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page

  var options = {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
    }
  }

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url_base + url_ext, options);
  var blob = response.getBlob().setName(pdfName + '.pdf');
  if (email) {
    var mailOptions = {
      attachments:blob, htmlBody:htmlbody
    }
MailApp.sendEmail(
      email, 
      subject+" (" + pdfName +")", 
      "html content only", 
      mailOptions);

MailApp.sendEmail(
      Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(), 
      "FRWD "+subject+" (" + pdfName +")", 
      "html content only", 
      mailOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

MailApp.sendEmail method takes first argument as "the addresses of the recipients, separated by commas"
I hope this document link helps you further understanding the API. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app

Comment: Could you please vote the answer as "This answer is useful" instead of "This answer is not useful" if it solves your issue?

Comment: @Jiffyjjackson Please accept this answer.